# Text rendered without space in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I came across a wired behaviour in chrome as the first word(**if it has exact two letters**) in paragraph doesn't have space even when the space has been given in the code.

I have narrowed it down and found by removing `break-word` ,it renders properly and also by giving `float` to P tag or by using `clear` property to P tag since the parent heading tag has been given `float`,the text renders properly with space.

My question is why it happends for first two letters alone, try changing the first word to any, other than two letters you can see the space between words.

**Fiddle below(updated)**

```css
h2{float:left;width:100%;}
.wrap{word-wrap:break-word;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<h2>heading</h2>
<p>Lo ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mollis leo ut vulputate tristique. Cras at bibendum enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean iaculis ullamcorper sapien ut vehicula. Sed felis nisi, eleifend eu augue nec, sodales malesuada dolor. Quisque et risus quam. Maecenas ligula justo, auctor nec erat maximus, maximus tincidunt ipsum. Fusce bibendum magna in felis luctus, eu imperdiet orci accumsan. Aliquam interdum sagittis tellus, eu volutpat velit dignissim nec. Vivamus accumsan sagittis diam id maximus. Nam diam purus, accumsan in felis non, rutrum aliquet quam. In ac libero arcu. Mauris semper augue ipsum, vitae porta nulla iaculis non. Praesent a fringilla est, a pharetra tellus.</p>
</div>
```

[image: text without space]

Comment: This problem seems to disappear as soon as I remove float from the h2. Any specific reason you are floating the headline? In combination with the 100% width it doesn’t seem to make the most sense.

Comment: @CBroe yes i am aware of removing float will fix this issue, but like to know why it happens in chrome alone that too for two letter word ,may be its chrome bug...

Comment: Pretty sure it’s a bug. (Clearing the floating on the paragraph fixes it as well.)

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

> the word-break CSS property is used to specify whether to break lines
>   within words.

The allowed values are:

```
/* Keyword values */
word-break: normal; 
word-break: break-all; 
word-break: keep-all;

/* Global values */
word-break: inherit;
word-break: initial;
word-break: unset;
```

break-word is not an allowed value, so I changed the value, then I removed the `float` attribute to your `h2`.

```css
h2{width:100%;}
.wrap{word-break:keep-all;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<h2>heading</h2>
<p>Lo ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mollis leo ut vulputate tristique. Cras at bibendum enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean iaculis ullamcorper sapien ut vehicula. Sed felis nisi, eleifend eu augue nec, sodales malesuada dolor. Quisque et risus quam. Maecenas ligula justo, auctor nec erat maximus, maximus tincidunt ipsum. Fusce bibendum magna in felis luctus, eu imperdiet orci accumsan. Aliquam interdum sagittis tellus, eu volutpat velit dignissim nec. Vivamus accumsan sagittis diam id maximus. Nam diam purus, accumsan in felis non, rutrum aliquet quam. In ac libero arcu. Mauris semper augue ipsum, vitae porta nulla iaculis non. Praesent a fringilla est, a pharetra tellus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't change the problem, your main problem is the float attribute on the h2 tag(are you sure you need it?)

Comment: Yes i am aware of removing float will fix this issue, but like to know why it happens in chrome alone that too for two letter word ,any specific technical reason?

Answer (score 0):

add `white-space: pre-wrap;`  to keep the space.

```css
h2{float:left;width:100%;}
.wrap{word-break:break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; /* Chrome; W3C standard */}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<h2>heading</h2>
<p>Lo ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mollis leo ut vulputate tristique. Cras at bibendum enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean iaculis ullamcorper sapien ut vehicula. Sed felis nisi, eleifend eu augue nec, sodales malesuada dolor. Quisque et risus quam. Maecenas ligula justo, auctor nec erat maximus, maximus tincidunt ipsum. Fusce bibendum magna in felis luctus, eu imperdiet orci accumsan. Aliquam interdum sagittis tellus, eu volutpat velit dignissim nec. Vivamus accumsan sagittis diam id maximus. Nam diam purus, accumsan in felis non, rutrum aliquet quam. In ac libero arcu. Mauris semper augue ipsum, vitae porta nulla iaculis non. Praesent a fringilla est, a pharetra tellus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `white-space:pre-wrap` too fixed this issue , can i get the link where it has been mentioned as chrome w3c standard to include this property